# Installing Ubuntu on Lenovo IdeaTab Lynx K3011

Tags: uefi, lenovo, lynx

This is my first forum post. I recently purchased a Lenovo IdeaTab Lynx K3011 equipped from the factory with Windows 8. I have been using Ubuntu for years and want to install Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 on the device. Enter problems...

I cannot make the device boot to USB. FastBoot and Secure Boot have been disabled. I have tried several different Bootable USB and partition schemes (including EFI) with no joy. Can someone with experience using this product guide me in the right direction? Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that you have to depress vol up and down simultaneously while powering up, then release then when the backlight comes on, and the depress them both simultaneously again to enter the bios setup utility